# How to connect and send files/messages between two android devices over wifi using a third android device as wifi access-point?

Tags: android

I want to develop an application where two android devices (running android 2.X) connect to each other for sharing data using wifi access-point created by another android device (using the wifi hotspot). Any android device running android 2.2 or over can be used as hotspot. That is not a problem. The main thing is to connect two android device using that access-point for sending/receiving messages.

Answer (score 0):

well I'm not an android developer but the pattern should be the same:

There are many ways to make a device declare itself as a hotspot. The simplest I can think of is to install a whatever adhook program that does that for you or whatever other program that uses the wifi capailities of the android device or any other connectify program or you can write one yourself

see this search [use android as a router](https://www.google.de/search?sourceid=chrome&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&ie=UTF-8&q=use%20connectify%20on%20android#hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=3im&tbo=d&channel=cs&sclient=psy-ab&q=use%20android%20as%20a%20router&oq=use%20android%20as%20a%20router&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i8i30l3.6873.9729.0.9834.23.19.0.4.4.0.226.2498.0j17j1.18.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.MgRyim6mpY0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.bGE&fp=87026341a487d4eb&bpcl=40096503&biw=1920&bih=1064)

Second you have to think how other devices are going to connect to this mobile "server" is this going to be just a bridge or what? how are you going to authenticate the devices to communicate with each other

And finally you have to think how to the devices are going to communicate. Do you want to use an FTP protocol for file transfer or what exactly?

These are all questions you have to think about and without concrete project requirements it is difficult to help further

Comment: any android device running android 2.2 or over can be used as hotspot. That is not a problem. The main thing is to connect two android device using that acess-point for sending/receiving messages.

Comment: is internet connectivity always present on the hotspot device?

Comment: no internet connection required in the hotspot device. Communication between the two android devices is needed.......